# Login area on an ASP.NET / C# web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe

i'm pretty new to ASP.NET and C# programming via VS2013,
my question is more an advice request;

I'm now creating a web page and it has a top bar with logo buttons and a login area, which controls an iFrame below.

The login area is made of 2 text-boxes (for e-mail and password) and a 'Login' button, and i want this part to change to something else (like a label saying 'Welcome {name}') in a case of correct login.

My first choice was to putt that login area inside an iFrame and make 2 'mini-sites', one with login and one with what i wish to show after a correct login - and make it change inside the iFrame, but i'm pretty sure there's a better option using the ASP.NET tools, can anyone give me some tip about a better way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using an `iframe` at al?

Comment: @woz - like I've said, i'm pretty new to all this subject and i'm using what i know from knowledge i had with HTML - the last tool i used to create websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a compelling reason to use an iframe, don't. Typically, you would redirect to the application after successful login. You can set the `defaultUrl` in Web.config, which is the page to go to after successful login by calling [`FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka5ffkce%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms defaultUrl="Default.aspx" loginUrl="Login.aspx" timeout="20" protection="None" cookieless="UseCookies"/>
</authentication>
```

If you're going for a single-page app, call a login method via Web API and alter the page accordingly with JavaScript. Make sure no sensitive data is loading before authentication.